# FileNotFoundError when specifying correct path

Tags: python

I have a main.py file in the following directory:

```
/Users/username/Projects/maps/Debugging/genericbot/main.py
```

This script main.py imports a function from a db.py file (through symlink described below), and executes it:

```
/Users/username/Projects/maps/Debugging/genericbot/other_project/db.py
```

I created a symlink between the two like so:

```
ln -s /Users/username/Projects/other_project
/Users/username/Projects/maps/Debugging/genericbot/other_project
```

The importing goes fine, however when I want to open a file, by running the following code in the /other_project/db.py folder like so:

```
import pickle, os

database_filename = "/Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.p"

def load_db():
    db = pickle.load( open( database_filename, "rb" ) )
    return db
```

It returns the following error, despite the path being absolute and correct:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.p'
```

I've tried specifying the absolute path like so (to the link):

```
/Users/username/Projects/maps/Debugging/genericbot/other_project/db.p
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Any way to solve this?

Comment: You are mssing y in your `db.py` filename in `database_filename`

Comment: No, I guess I haven't clarified properly. The db.py file (that gets loaded, and the function is imported from) is not the issue, the db.p file (a pickle file in the same location) is the issue.

Comment: You did not mention db.p file in your question, you are symlinking whole directory?, also what result you get when you try to do in terminal: `stat /Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.p` do you even have that file there?

Comment: Yes I'm symlinking the entire directory.

Strangely enough stat /Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.p does not work, even though the file is there, same for stat /Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.py

But when I just do the folder it works:
stat /Users/username/Projects/other_project/
16777220 9823233 drwxr-xr-x 9 username staff 0 306 "Sep 23 20:43:57 2017" "Sep 23 19:35:53 2017" "Sep 23 19:35:53 2017" "Sep 22 11:54:39 2017" 4096 0 0 /Users/username/Projects/other_project/

Comment: actually the python file works too (forgot to change it back to my own links): stat /Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.py
16777220 9821576 -rw-r--r-- 1 username staff 0 620 "Sep 23 20:44:38 2017" "Sep 23 11:04:50 2017" "Sep 23 11:04:50 2017" "Sep 22 11:20:59 2017" 4096 8 0 /Users/username/Projects/other_project/db.py

Comment: There was a space after my filename.... so it was ".../db.p ". Thanks for the help! pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This might be filesystem level issue when symlinking, etc, ensure you have files in right place, from terminal:

```
ls -alh /Users/username/Projects/other_project/
```

ensure your `db.p` is there, you might want find exact location of that file with find:

```
find /Users/username/Projects/ -name 'db.p'
```

Comment: No, I guess I haven't clarified properly. The db.py file (that gets loaded, and the function is imported from) is not the issue, the db.p file (a pickle file in the same location) is the issue

Comment: Yea seems like I got the filename wrong. For some reason I was saving it as ".../db.p ", with a trailing space. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.